# How can I return only the string value of an object from a MongoDB array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

valueOf() returns this:

```
[
   {},
   { toUser: '5ed9d49c7e516616600eb693' },       
   { toUser: '5ed9d49c7e516616600eb693' },       
   { toUser: '5ed9d49c7e516616600eb693' },       
   { toUser: '5ed9d3897e516616600eb692' }        
]
```

I want to return only the value like "5ed9d3897e516616600eb692" or whatever toUser has. How?

Comment: could you show us the full code?

Comment: do you need array of id strings instead of array of object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in a couple of different ways, the best of which is using [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/):

```
db.collection.distinct("toUser")
```

Output will be:

```
[
    '5ed9d49c7e516616600eb693',
    '5ed9d49c7e516616600eb693',
    '5ed9d49c7e516616600eb693',
    '5ed9d3897e516616600eb692'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` and inside callback check if the object has any key using `Object.keys` and length. If it has k then push the value using `Object.values` into the accumulator array

```js
let data = [{},
  {
    toUser: '5ed9d49c7e516616600eb693'
  },
  {
    toUser: '5ed9d49c7e516616600eb693'
  },
  {
    toUser: '5ed9d49c7e516616600eb693'
  },
  {
    toUser: '5ed9d3897e516616600eb692'
  }
];
let filterdValue = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const objKey = Object.keys(curr);
  if (objKey.length > 0) {
    acc.push(...Object.values(curr))
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(filterdValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to convert object to string

```
> db.objectidToStringDemo.aggregate([{$project: {toUser: {$toString: "$toUser"}}}]);
```